# Very loose bound on sum of first binomials

Tags: inequality, binomial-coefficients

Let $n\geq k\geq 2$. Is it always true that $$\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+\cdots+\binom{n}{k}\leq n^k?$$

The left-hand side is dominated by the term $\dfrac{n^k}{k!}$, so the statement should be true. But how can we show it rigorously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The case $n=2$ can be verified easily. Also $k=2$ means that:
$$
1+n+\frac{n^2-n}{2}=\frac{n^2+n+2}{2}\leq n^2
$$
which is true for $n\geq 2$. So for the rest we assume $n,k\geq 3$. Now observe the following inequality for $1\leq i\leq n$:
$$
\binom{n}{i}=\frac{n(n-1)\dots(n-i+1)}{i!}\leq n(n-1)^{i-1}.
$$
Then we can use this inequality to bound the original sum:

\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+\cdots+\binom{n}{k}&\leq 1+n\sum_{i=1}^k(n-1)^{i-1}\\
&= 1+n\frac{(n-1)^{k}-1}{n-2}\\
&=\frac{n(n-1)^{k}-2}{n-2}\\
&\leq\frac{n(n-1)^{k}}{n-2}\\
&\leq n(n-1)^{k-2}(n+1)\\
&\leq n(n-1)^{k-3}n^2\\
&\leq n^{k}.
\end{align*}

Comment: I think your second-to-last inequality $\dfrac{n(n-1)^k}{n-2}\leq n(n-1)^{k-1}$ is not quite correct. Also, are you using $n\geq 3$ anywhere? (since you separated out the $n=2$ case.)

Comment: I am using $n\geq 3$ everywhere. And you were right about the inequality. I have changed the proof.